# How can use an array of objects in React with Typescript with an interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects where the data is stored in an JSON file. Here is how the JSON file looks like:

```
[
{
"_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
"index": 0,
"email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Wendi Mooney"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
   "_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
   "index": 1,
   "nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Janine Barrett"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Odonnell Savage"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Patty Owen"
  }
]
},
```

After that I have to use this object as props in another component (someComponent) and I made an interface:

```
interface Props {
data: [
{
  _id: string;
  index: number;
  email: string;
  nameList: { id: number; name: string };
}
];
}
```

Yet after that I get the current error:

```
Type '({ _id: string; index: number; nameList: { id: number; name: string; }[]; email?: undefined; } | { index: number; email: string; nameList: { id: number; name: string; }[]; _id?: undefined; } | { _id: string; index: number; email: string; nameList: ({ ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; })[]; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type '[{ _id: string; index: number; email: string; nameList: { id: number; name: string; }; }]'.
  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
someComponent.tsx(3, 3): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
```

What may seem to be the problem?

Comment: nameList is not defined to be an array, and I don't see whats the purpose of `data`

Comment: 'data' is just the variable where I store the data so I dont pass in the properties on their own. data = {data}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `data` on your `Props` type but not for your input data object.

> 'data' is just the variable where I store the data so I dont pass in the properties on their own. data = {data}

`data = {data}` - Here the `data` should be specified with your `data` type of `Props`. If you haven't specified anything typescript will take its properties and creates an object. That is the reason you are getting the error.

```
Type '({ _id: string; index: number; nameList: { id: number; name: string; }[]; email?: undefined; } | { index: number; email: string; nameList: { id: number; name: string; }[]; _id?: undefined; } | { _id: string; index: number; email: string; nameList: ({ ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; })[]; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type '[{ _id: string; index: number; email: string; nameList: { id: number; name: string; }; }]'.
```

Provide a type for your input data or at least specify `any` so that the error will be resolved.

Check this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsgCZxhwBcyA2sSQQ48gPrCk05hSgDmAbmaNQpCAA8aIAK4BbAEbQhLEhFlxgAGy49+ylSDiyIAGWDca+ZBylzFUAckPGdvEH2QBfWgF19JTwY-QkDCBAwQbjIKamQ4EABPZABeOgYiFnZOZAAiADYAJnlSAFYYeTgAZgAWOAAOGABGBABOAAZKjraSkoQcgBphUQkaNsGWNQ1tXNkEUgi4TVIACwwliBAAAXFoCQA6cNkB4WdTczAaehUma5IbZDHhFlOaHIB1DdJgZABZDAiIAljtdPOMVBlbvcCmDri9cgAJNaaDAAdzgSTey2AkGWEDgpGBKlBwh8YOJJAhJCyr0KxTKFQQlQgJTg1RgCDgJQgdS5dUahLuIDEkmQjRhTiMZwsaWulJU90etwlLlyACl4qAUAAhOBQKAQMBgAWMcngp4ibJi80kOE5ADy8xAIAgmk0yAAynAAG5wPgQY0BcUU63WbLQkO21AUMBJO0ojYBrzi0kMYnBMIRKLSLDkSCkAAiMRo6GweFS+ByubgORoVc8QA)

Comment: Yeah this seems to work if you have an variable but what if I just used data as a prop, prop destruction. Like this :       <SomeComponent data={data} />. I cant really give 'data' an type.

Comment: You can try something like this `<SomeComponent data={data as any} />,` or you can even create a type for that and use that.